# How to break (rdlc) Table header into two lines along with data?

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, rdlc, reportviewer

I am trying to generate invoice with thermal printers, **as the width of the page is less. I am trying to divide Table Header and data into multiple lines**. How can i achieve this thing in WinForm Application using RDLC.

I have attached the Image which i am trying to achieve. 
[Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGrkF.jpg)

Comment: You should allways include the code you are currently using. This makes it easier for others to point out what you need to change. Currently we would have to writethe entire code for you

Comment: Currently i am using ReportViewer. Which is code free and easy way for designing RDLC files.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is too late for this answer but it may be useful to someone.

In the header Insert a row below, there will be two lines of header, in the first select all the columns and combine them, type the title for the product, in the second line type the columns QTY, PRICE, EXPIRE, in the detail insert a row below, there will be two detail rows, in the first select all the columns and combine it, assign the Product Name field, in the second row of the detail configure the fields QTY, PRICE, EXPIRE
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3c5W.png)

Regards,